# Counting from different categories within the same query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to make a query from a table in Access that would give me totals for different types of product based off of 2 categories, all within one query. For example my Table looks as follows:

| Type | Description 1 | Description 2 | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| New | Shiny | Black | 1/1/2022 |
| New | Black | Dull | 1/1/2022 |
| Old | Shiny | Grey | 1/1/2022 |
| Old | Grey | Dull | 1/1/2022 |

The query results that I want to receive are as follows:

| Description | New | Old |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Shiny | 1 | 1 |
| Black | 2 | 0 |
| Dull | 1 | 1 |
| Grey | 0 | 2 |

The dataset that I am working with isn't as clean as my example shown here and is causing some of the issues. I never had an issue with the code running, but I just felt that there had to be an easier way that I was missing.

They way I was doing it originally just turned into a bunch of separate query's and was messy to get around. I essentially wrote a query to separate the table into new and old types. From there I used a bunch of

```
SUM(IIF( Description 1 = "x" OR Description 2 = "x") AS X
SUM(IIF( Description 1 = "y" OR Description 2 = "y") AS Y
```

expressions to count my totals for each of the objects. This would give me a query where all the totals were displayed in columns. Then I created a separate query to join these data sets together into a presentable manner, but it was turning into too much for how many different "types" I had.

I was just looking for a way to combine all of this into 1 query that would make pulling reports much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Strongly advise not to use space in naming convention nor reserved words as names. **Date** is a reserved word.

Consider:

Query1

```
SELECT Type, Description1 AS D, [Date], 1 AS Category FROM Table1
UNION SELECT Type, Description2, [Date], 2 FROM Table1;
```

UNION will not allow duplicate rows. Use UNION ALL to include all records, even if there are duplicates. There is no query designer or wizard for UNION - must type or copy/paste in SQLView of query builder.

Query2

```
TRANSFORM Nz(Count(Query1.Category),0) AS CountOfCategory
SELECT Query1.D
FROM Query1
GROUP BY Query1.D
PIVOT Query1.Type;
```

Comment: Okay this is doing exactly what I want minus one small caveat. Its just giving me the location of each of the descriptions per type, and not the quantity of how much each of the descriptions appears.

Comment: I tested with data provided and output is exactly what you show as desired result, except in alphabetical order of Description.